# Rename jQuery tabs?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

Is it possible to rename all the tabs in a jQuery UI tab control? My tabs are numbered from 1..N, and it is possible to remove a tab from it. I want to "rename" the remaining tabs so they are numbered 1,2,3,4,5,6, and 1,2,3,5,6,7 when you remove the fourth tab. They should end up named by their 1-based index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [Tabs_3](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs), then it's very easy. Simply:

```
var n = 1;
$('#example > ul span').each(function() { this.innerHTML=n;n++; });
```

Comment: your inner block can be this.innerHTML=n++;

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I should have realized Tabs_3 picks up changes to the underlying HTML.

Comment: Mike: Can it? I'm suspicious of mixing numeric operators with magic strings (like innerHTML) - do all browsers support that correctly? (I can't check now)

Comment: Vegard: Tabs_3 simply modifies the style properties of the dom, and adds some event handlers; a quick check with Firebug showed it didn't mutate the dom at all.